# Designing multi-tenant app in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, multi-tenant

I'm implementing a multi-tenant app with Rails. My approach is not to use the postgres inbuilt multi-tenant feature and add a column to record the subdomain. That is where the question is :)

Let's get this example

```
class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organisation
end
```

I'm thinking about two approaches here:

**Approach 1**

add a `subdomain` column only to `organisations`

- pros - The way how relational databases should work \0/
- cons - When I have more complex queries , that will make my code slow

**Approach 2**

add a `subdomain` column to both `organisations` and `users`

- pros - This will make queries faster
- cons - I'm going against the relational databases

So the question is, what sort of a method I should follow between above two, or are there a different approach that I didn't think about?

Comment: I see there is a vote for closing this question based on it's an opinion based one. However I disagree with it because this question is more about design decisions and I've outlined my thoughts. I'm not asking a question like what is the best editor VIM or Sublime ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We run a multi-tenant Rails app with slightly fewer than 500 table-backed classes, and if I had to guess I'd say around 400 of them relate to client data.

Client-specific attributes are held in the `Client` model, but we add the `client_id` to every client table with a not null constraint on the database. Only a minority of them are indexed, though because they are generally only accessed through a parent record.

We do not have to worry about setting the client id because the model will generally have:

```
class Child

  after_initialize do
    self.client ||= parent.client
  end

end
```

We add the `client_id` to many tables because we have a lot of code that does:

```
@books = current_user.client.books
```

... so in those cases we'll have an association directly from `Client` to the model, and `client_id` is indexed.

We add the `client_id` to all tables, though, because we very often, for operational or unusual reasons, want to be able to find all of the relevant records for a client ...

```
MarketingText.where(client: Client.snowbooks).group(:type).count
```

... and having to go through a parent record is just inconvenient.

Also, because we made the decision to do this on all client-specific tables, we do not have to make the decision on each one.

So to get to your question, what I would do is add the subdomain to the `Organisation` only. However, I would add the `organisation_id` column to every table holding Organisation-specific data.

If you have a lot of clients but you are going to be generally familiar with their subdomain, then I would write a meta-program method on the Organisation that lets you use:

```
Organisation.some_subdomain
```

... to get the required organisation, then find the child records (in any table) with an association directly from the Organisation model ...

```
Organisation.some_subdomain.users
Organisation.some_subdomain.prices
Organisation.some_subdomain.whatevers
```

Comment: How do you deal with associations? If you have belongs_to :something , how do you prevent from user posting a id that belongs to other organization?

Comment: @GorillaApe I think it's a combination of filtering what users can see, e.g. by referring to `current_user.client.invoices` instead of `Invoice.all`, and can-can.

Answer (score 1):

my opinion will go Approach number one, couple reasons for this

1. using relational database provided with activerecord + scopes will make writing software easier, also if you have more objects under organization later for example transactions, items (beside users),

I have a project with multi tenant capabilities and below is sample of design in my project

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users     
  # transaction
    has_many :transactions
    has_many :journals , :through => :transactions
  # item
    has_many :items
    # other has_many ...
end
```

and in controller you can use eager loading to minimize query (includes / joins)

```
@company.includes(:users).scope_filter_here.search(params[:q])
```

2. approach number 1 is more user friendly compared with approach number 2 as it's more simple to user writing your url address, the less url to type is better (personal opinion).